# open text file with from root path

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, ifstream

I was wonder how to specify a specify path from root in c++ on windows. I tried

```
ifstream inputFrom;    
inputFrom.open("c:\Users\bvarghese2155\Desktop\primer_problem_8.txt");
```

but there was error.

Comment: replace \ in the string with \\

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag it as C++11,

In C++11, you can use raw string,

```
inputFrom.open(R"(c:\Users\bvarghese2155\Desktop\primer_problem_8.txt)");
```

In old C++ (without raw string, you have to)

```
inputFrom.open("c:\\Users\\bvarghese2155\\Desktop\\primer_problem_8.txt");
```

because \ alone is escape character and double \ is the real \ character.